# What are your suggestions for a different logging method in UWP?

Tags: c#, logging, uwp, storage

During the UWP conversion of an application that was previously designed as a winform, errors occurred in my logging method and I had to change the System.IO reference to Storage. As a result of this change, when the synchronous method started to work asynchronously, I got errors about the request to use the file at the same time. Then I came up with a simple solution by creating the class I mentioned below but this quick amateurish approach do you think is correct?

```
public class Logging_UWP
{
    private List<string> CompletedLog = new List<string>();

    private string machineCode = string.Empty;

    public Logging_UWP(string MachineCode)
    {
        machineCode = MachineCode;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> WriteLog());
    }

    public void WriteLogSync(string NewLog)
    {
        CompletedLog.Add(NewLog);
    }

    private async void WriteLog()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string NewLog in CompletedLog)
                {
                    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                    StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(machineCode + ".log", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                    var stream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                    using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(stream.Size + 1))
                    {
                        using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outputStream))
                        {
                            dataWriter.WriteString(String.Format("\n[{0}-{1}] >>> {2}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), NewLog));
                            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                            await outputStream.FlushAsync();      
                        }             
                    }                      
                }
                if (CompletedLog.Count > 0)
                    CompletedLog.Clear();
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }
    }
} '''
```

Comment: Why you use While-true block in the WriteLog?

Comment: I can remove the "while" with a small change. But is that the only problem?

Comment: The problem is you open the file synchronously, it will not waiting for previous writing process finish, and run the new writing action for the same file. so it will throw file was using exception